# GWT GAE app engine modules using appengine-skeleton-archetype

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, gwt, google-eclipse-plugin

I tried to create a new maven project using com.google.appengine.archetypes:appengine-skeleton-archetype and it generate appname, appname-ear, appname-war. Based on what I read to convert backends to module, I need to have at least default module. How do I change appname-war to default or add a new module name default, because every time I did that, the default module doesn't seems to be appeared on the outside of appname project (the parent project).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer. I just need to refresh the project and I can make the default module.

Comment: How do you refresh a project?  You mean in Eclipse File=>Refresh?